# C - Retrieving the values of an int array from va_arg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the individual values of an int array that was passed to a function with a variable number of parameters ...

The function call looks like this (the two char arrays are irrelevant for the problem):

```
int arr[5];

testFunc(3, charArr1, charArr2, intArr);
```

In testFunc() I try to retrieve the values like this (for the char arrays it's working perfectly fine):

```
va_start(ptr, cnt);
if (cnt > 1) {
    for (i=0; i < cnt; i++) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                strcpy(charArr1, va_arg(ptr, char *));
                break;
            case 1:
                strcpy(charArr2, va_arg(ptr, char *));
                break;
            case 2:
                for (j=0; j<5; j++) { 
                    sprintf(buffer, "%d ", va_arg(ptr, int *));
                    strcat(message, buffer);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
va_end(ptr);
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is that each one of the five values in intArr is retrieved and written to the char array "buffer". The contents of this (initially empty) buffer are then copied (actually concatenated to) into the char array "message".
Assuming the five int values in the int array were 2, 5, 3, 9, 8, and I would output message as a string, then in the end the output should be "2 5 3 9 8".

What do I have to change in my code to get there?

Any help is appreciated! ...

Comment: you pass *one* int array, call `va_var( ptr, int *)` five times *and* print the result (`int *`) with `%d`.

Comment: I'm aware of that and oddly enough it does output five (different) values: Some very long int value that I don't recognise, and the first four of my int values ...

Comment: What I would like to do is something like this: va_arg(ptr, int *)[j] ... to get each individual int value. But that's causing a SegFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `va_arg` 5 times when you should only call it once: `intArr` is a single parameter.

Use temporary variable instead:

```
int * temp;
```

...

```
case 2:
    temp = va_arg(ptr, int*);
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) { 
        snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "%d ", temp[i]);
```

But I question the need to use var args function at all. Usually it is way more efficient to have constant number of arguments and pass `NULL` instead when parameter should be empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solution is what I was looking for. You may be right about the use of variadic functions. I thought it would be a more "elegant" solution than passing NULL. I'll think about changing that ...